# Vuforia augment reality windows

Tags: unity-game-engine, exe, augmented-reality, vuforia

Can you please tell me, if `vuforia` can run on a PC? I have tried to make an .EXE file, but it does not work.

Please tell me how can I run vuforia apps on my PC? Should I build it for Windows store using Unity and then run it on Windows 8?

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't work? errors? no response?

Comment: I mean it doesn't run on pc mode

Comment: Does it build successfully?

Comment: Yeah it builds successfully and also prompt for screen size and other resolution. And then when i press the start button it shuts down the application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can you please tell me vuforia can run on pc

Answer is **No**. You cannot build windows or mac app with Vuforia.  Vuforia is only supported on Mobile Platforms (iOS, Android).

But you want to test on Windows, you can run your app and test in unity Editor mode with webcamera attached. I hope it will answer your question.

Comment: Windows is now supported via Unity3D and Windows 10 UWP SDK (Early Access Preview)

Answer (score 1):

1. download unity from the unity website , install & run
2. download vuforia and vuforia sample for unity on vuforia website
3. create unity project and add vuforia package to the project

There are some tutorials for you for importing the samples and ofcourse you need to get a key with the name of your project.

Have a look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HnjbTytHH6U

Comment: It's a reasonable video but you must also read the comments, there's a lot of details not covered in the video that the comments describe.

Answer (score 0):

For now, and without plugin, [the answer is **no**](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/general-discussion/wish-list). But,

1. Vuforia is [work on supporting win 10](https://developer.vuforia.com/support/early-access), so maybe months later, you can develop a win 10 universal app.
2. There is some plugin support build the app for windows and Mac, it costs much money. The plugin is provided by [maximarouf](https://github.com/maximrouf/VuforiaStandaloneBuild)
3. As the answers above, I agree that it is enough to run in unity editor for presantation and test.

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia now has a [Windows 10 Early Access Program](https://developer.vuforia.com/support/early-access). You can apply for participation and may get access to the Windows 10 UWP SDK.

However, it currently only supports Intel based devices, like the Surface Book and Surface Pro series.

Alternatively, you can use the Unity3D Plugin to build an app which works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

No vuforia is not supported . U will get Vuforiawrapper.dll missing error when you try to .
Instead what you could do is , make an APK , Download Bluestacks and install it in PC and emulate your vuforia app in PC . But no Vuforia is not made for PC. It supports UWP though which means Windows Tablet , Windows Phone, Hololens .